# "Intelligent" selection between ";" or "." depending if there is one of next parameters set

Tags: macros, pdftex, conditionals, ifthenelse

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\ABC}[4]{foo}
\renewcommand{\ABC}[4]{%
\textbf{#1:}\\
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{A #2.\ }%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{B #3.\ }%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{C #4.\ }%
\\
}
\ABC{Foo}{x}{}{z}
\ABC{Foy}{x}{y}{}
\ABC{Bar}{}{y}{}
\ABC{Baz}{}{y}{z}
\ABC{Zoo}{x}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Now optional "A", "B", "C" sections are always separated by ".":

```
Foo:
A x. C z.
Foy:
A x. B y.
Bar:
B y.
Baz:
B y. C z.
Zoo:
A x.
```

I would love this macro to be "intelligent" to put ";" instead of "." if there is next section:

```
Foo:
A x; C z.
Foy:
A x; B y.
Bar:
B y.
Baz:
B y; C z.
Zoo:
A x.
```

What is most concise way of expressing this in $\LaTeX$ ?

Is it really some conditional:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{ \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{ \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{...
```

or using combination or "and", "or" statements,

or is there an other, more concise way, maybe using some variable?

(I use pdflatex)

Answer (score 3):

Easy with `xparse`. Check whether the argument is not empty and add the required bit to a sequence, then deliver the sequence items separated by “semicolon and space”. Finally, print the period.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ABC}{mmmm}
 {
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{#1:}\\
  \gw_abc:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_gw_abc_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gw_abc:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_gw_abc_seq
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gw_abc_seq { A~#1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gw_abc_seq { B~#2 } }
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #3 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gw_abc_seq { C~#3 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_gw_abc_seq { ;~ }.
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ABC{Foo}{x}{}{z}

\ABC{Foy}{x}{y}{}

\ABC{Bar}{}{y}{}

\ABC{Baz}{}{y}{z}

\ABC{Zoo}{x}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]